# Map is blurry when mobile viewport is set

Tags: openlayers-2

we are creating a map using openlayers 2. It is working fine on PC, but on mobile devices map looks blurry. I also tried using incognito mode but I get same result, so there is no problem with cached tiles.
Viewport is set as:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Screenshots from iphone,
this is without viewport set:
[image]

and this is using viewport from above:
[image]

Do you have any solution?

Comment: the two screenshots seems to be taken at different zoom level.

Comment: Yes, zoom levels are not exactly the same but still pretty close.
Same problem is here: http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/openlayers/mobile-resize.html